# Android SpeechRecognizer test data

Tags: android, testing, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm writing an Android application using a SpeechRecognizer and a RecognitionListener, and I'd like to implement some repeatable tests for the functionality of the components that use these objects. Is there any way to test speech recognition on Android short of actually installing the app on a device and talking to it? Preferably in a consistent repeatable way. I have looked into stuff like a simple built in API, and workaround solutions like a method of passing a file to the recognizer, and come up with nothing on those fronts.